# Unix shell - manipulation and filtering of text

Tags: shell, unix, filter, terminal

I'm trying to solve a task using Unix shell. I have the following output:

```
  2 Accepted 10.0.0.202
  8 Failed 10.0.0.202
 11 Failed 10.0.0.202
  1 Accepted 151.62.163.222
  3 Failed 151.62.163.222
```

I want to find out for each of the IP-adresses how many failed and how many accepted there are, and print it like this: IP-adr failedAttempts acceptedAttempts.

Does anyone have any input on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 3):

GNU awk has array-of-arrays, so it's quite easy:

```
processToProduceOutput | gawk '
    {count[$3][$2] += $1} 
    END {
        for (ip in count)
            print ip, 0 + count[ip]["Accepted"], 0 + count[ip]["Failed"]
    }
'
```

which produces

```
151.62.163.222 1 3
10.0.0.202 2 19
```

To make the output prettier, pipe into `| column -t`

The `0 + count...` will allow an IP with no accepted/failed to show 0 in the appropriate column.

---

There's also this overly-clever perl

```
perl -lane '
    $c{$F[2]}{$F[1]} += $F[0];
}{ 
    printf "%s %d %d\n", $_, map {0+$_} $c{$_}->@{"Accepted","Failed"} for keys %c;
'
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done rather elegantly with [GNU Datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) 1.3 and its [crosstab/pivot](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/Crosstab.html) operation:

```
$ datamash -W crosstab 3,2 sum 1 < data
        Accepted        Failed
10.0.0.202      2       19
151.62.163.222  1       3
```

Answer (score 2):

I added an ip for testing an edge case:

```
(pi 695) $ cat /tmp/x 
 2 Accepted 10.0.0.202
  8 Failed 10.0.0.202
 11 Failed 10.0.0.202
  1 Accepted 151.62.163.222
  3 Failed 151.62.163.222
111 Failed 8.8.8.8
222 Failed 8.8.8.8
(pi 696) $ awk '
  {ip[$3]++}                  # keep track of ALL ip addresses
  $2=="Accepted" {a[$3]+=$1}  # keep track of all Accepted
  $2=="Failed"   {f[$3]+=$1}  # keep track of all Failed
  END{
    for(i in ip){             # for every ip seen
      print i, f[i]+0, a[i]+0 # print ip, failures, and accepts
    }
  }' /tmp/x
151.62.163.222 3 1
8.8.8.8 333 0
10.0.0.202 19 2
```

Comment: please add some whitespace to your awk

Answer (score 1):

The following `AWK` script could be used to do the task. Save the script in a file and then run the bash command : `$ awk -f scipt_file text_file`.

```
{
    if ($2 == "Failed") {
        if ($3 in failed)
            failed[$3] += $1
        else 
            failed[$3] = $1
    }

    else {
        if ($3 in accepted)
            accepted[$3] += $1
        else
            accepted[$3] = $1
    }
}

END {
    printf "%-16s\t%s\t%s\n", "IP", "Failed", "Accepted"
    for (ip in accepted) {
        if (ip in failed) {
            nfail = failed[ip] 
        } else 
            nfail = 0
        printf "%-16s\t%d\t%d\n", ip, nfail, accepted[ip]
    }

    for (ip in failed) {
        if (ip in accepted) {} 
        else {
            printf "%-16s\t%d\t%d\n", ip, failed[ip], 0 
        } 
    }
}
```

It prints :

```
IP                      Failed  Accepted
151.62.163.222          3       1
10.0.0.202              19      2
```